# Return NSBundle file path that is created before from an URL

Tags: ios

So I got a function:

```
    + (NSString *)dataFilePath:(BOOL)forSave {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dl.dropbox.com/u/35612216/sample.xml"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];  // Load XML data from web

// construct path within our documents directory
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *storePath = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.xml"];

// write to file atomically (using temp file)
[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];

return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:storePath ofType:@"xml"];
//return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"xml"];

}
```

And this seems to not work, but when I add a supporting file in my project (sample.xml) and just use this line:

```
return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"xml"];
```

It will work. But I need to get my XML data from the url instead of the supporting file (resource file)

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NSBundle` method loads the file from the app's bundle, while you've saved the file to the app's Documents directory (which are different locations).

All you need to do is `return storePath;` which will give you the `NSString` representation of where the file is located.